# How to create a matrix of functions dynamically

Tags: matlab, function, dynamic

I want to create a matrix of functions, however I'd like to dynamically generate it. For example:

```
myMatrix = zeros(3);
test = @(x) x*y;
for ii = 1:3
    myMatrix(ii) = test(ii);
end
```

something like that to generate: `@(y) [y, 2*y, 3*y]`

I do not have access to the `sym` library.

Comment: `y` is a number, a vector or a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a matrix of functions, but you can make cell of function handles, e.g.

```
cellOfFunctions = {};

for i = 1:3
    cellOfFunctions{end + 1} = @(y) y*i;
end
```

Then you can get each handle as follows (for the first function handle):

```
fh1 = cellOfFunctions{1};
```

Then execute it with `y = 3`:

```
result = fh1(3);
```

Comment: You can also execute the first function as `cellOfFunctions{1}(value)` etc

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your purposes, you can make a single function which generates the matrix you have in your example:

```
>> f = @(y) bsxfun(@times, 1:3, y(:));
>> f(2:5)
ans =
    2     4     6
    3     6     9
    4     8    12
    5    10    15
```